# Get the hostname from the hosts file

Tags: ansible

I would like to get another host from one of my templates.

Given the following `hosts` file:

```
[vm]
vm_hostname

[monitoring]
monitoring_hostname
```

How can I access `monitoring_hostname` from a template?

I tried:

```
monitor: {{ hostvars['monitoring'][0] }}
```

NB: I can't just use `monitor: monitoring_hostname` because my `hosts` file is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`groups` magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts), not `hostvars`:

```
monitor: "{{ groups['monitoring'][0] }}"
```